# How to apply Sendkeys Page Down?

Tags: excel, vba, sendkeys, pagedown

I am trying to send a page down keypress using VBA.

```vb
Set Myscreen = Sys.Screen, SYS is set as Set Sys = GetObject("C:\Program Files\Attachmate\E!E2K\Sessions\AS400-A.EDP")
```

I tried;

```
Myscreen.SendKeys "{PGDN}"  
Myscreen.SendKeys ("{PGDN}")
Myscreen.SendKeys ("<PGDN>")
Myscreen.SendKeys "{PAGE DOWN}"
Myscreen.SendKeys ("{PAGE DOWN}")
Myscreen.SendKeys ("<PAGE DOWN>")
Myscreen.SendKeys "{PAGE DN}"
Myscreen.SendKeys ("{PAGE DN}")
Myscreen.SendKeys ("<PAGE DN>")
Myscreen.SendKeys "{Down}"
Myscreen.SendKeys ("{Down}")
Myscreen.SendKeys ("<Down>") - this was the only that did anything, it moved the cursor down a line.
```

I got delete to work using `Myscreen.Sendkeys ("<DELETE>")`.

Comment: Have you tried with the second parameter at True, namely `SendKeys "{PGDN}", True` ?

Comment: I hadn't, but I just did and I get a message stating "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

Comment: I probably can't help you, sorry

Answer (score 0):

The correct [Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821075.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for {Page Down} should be

```
Option Explicit
Sub sndkey()
    '// to send multiple times try "{PGDN 5}"
    Application.SendKeys "{PGDN}"
End Sub
```

look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821075.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) & [SendKeys Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**Edit**

okay I have tested it works

```
Option Explicit
Sub sndkey()
    Dim Myscreen As Object
    Set Myscreen = Sys.Screen
    '// to send multiple times try "{PGDN 5}"
    Myscreen.SendKeys "{PGDN 6}"
End Sub
```

Comment: that was the first one that I tried. but for some reason "{DEL}" is the right syntax for delete but it wont work unless i put it in as ("<DELETE>"), the same way page down isnt working when I use what MSDN says

Comment: did you try removing `Myscreen`?  how did you defined MyScreen variable?

Comment: Set myscreen = Sys.Screen, if i remove the myscreen part it doesnt cause an issue, but it also doesnt really do anything, the screen wont go down a page if i just have Sendkeys "{PGDN}"

Comment: Set myscreen = Sys.Screen, SYS is set as Set Sys = GetObject("C:\Program Files\Attachmate\E!E2K\Sessions\AS400-A.EDP")

Comment: @user1787114 it wouldn't have hurt if you mentioned that you were using the attachmate version of SendKeys

Answer (score -1):

this is the correct syntax `Myscreen.SendKeys ("<rollup>")`

Comment: How does this differ from `Myscreen.SendKeys ("<Down>")` *syntactically*, and why is *rollup* appropriate to `send a page down keypress`?

Comment: @greybeard This syntax is specifically for the Attachmate library he is trying to use.