# PageDown Key in MainFrame Application

Tags: vba, excel

I want to login and navigate to another mainframe page.

I need to open three screens one after another.  After opening the first screen, a main menu should come back with shortcut key "PageDOWN".

In VBA using SendKeys.

```vb
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("")
Dim Sessions As Object
Dim System As Object
Set System = CreateObject("EXTRA.System")    
If (System Is Nothing) Then
    MsgBox "Could not create the EXTRA System object.  Stopping macro playback."
    Stop
End If
Set Sessions = System.Sessions
            
Dim Sess0 As Object
Set Sess0 = System.ActiveSession
Sess0.screen.putstring "pppx" 18, 35
Sess0.screen.SendKeys ("<Enter>")

Sess0.screen.putstring MainLoginID, 14, 17
Sess0.screen.putstring MainLoginPwd, 15, 17
Sess0.screen.SendKeys ("<Enter>")

If activescreen = "FOOD SYSTEMS" Then
    Sess0.screen.SendKeys ("<HOME>")
    Sess0.screen.putstring "21", 23, 7
    Sess0.screen.SendKeys ("<Enter>")
END IF
Sess0.screen.SendKeys "{PGDN}"
```

Trying

```vb
Sess0.screen.SendKeys "{PGDN}"  
Sess0.screen.SendKeys ("{PGDN}")
Sess0.screen.SendKeys ("<PGDN>")
```

Other than page down, all are working.

```vb
Sess0.screen.SendKeys ("<HOME>")
Sess0.screen.SendKeys ("<F7>")
```

There is similar post but didn't find solution for my issue  [Sendkeys Page Down not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31460447/sendkeys-page-down-not-working).

Comment: What program are you using here?

Comment: `Sess0.screen` doesn't look like part of the Excel object model, but if it's your own class and a standard SendKeys call, then you want a member of `VBA.KeyCodeConstants` in `Const vbKeyPageDown = 34 (&H22)`

Comment: hello,thanks for quick reply,but  if it's our own class and a standard SendKeys also other than page down..Sess0.screen.SendKeys ("<HOME>")..Sess0.screen.SendKeys ("<F7>") all are working can  tell me why we have issue with pagedown?

Comment: here we are using excel vba code         -Tim Williams

Comment: is this through ibms "personal communications"?

Comment: hello ThunderFrame  can you tell me how to be a member of VBA.KeyCodeConstants?

Comment: no nathan_Sav, its just sample macro to login mainframes application

Comment: http://docs.attachmate.com/extra/x-treme/apis/com/sendkeysmethod_con.htm lists the available codes for SendKeys.  I don't see PageDown there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone still looking for answer

```
SendKeys "<PA2>"
```

This worked for me.